# How can I add the image in edit text images in anywhere in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-bitmap

In my app I am going to pick the images from the gallery and put it to the edit text,user can put the images where ever in edit text field also user can type anything in edit text field if there is any idea can help.

**Emoticon.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.emoticon);
         Pick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pick);
         EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
         Pick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    // Picture from camera
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 10);

                }
            });
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
                if (requestCode == requestCode) {
                    // return from file upload
                    if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();
                        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc");
                        Drawable d = img.getDrawable();
                        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                        ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        EditText.setText(ss);      

                    }
                    }
         }
```

Comment: Can you please clear your question. You want One Image per edittext or the multiple images per edittext.

Comment: multiple images per edittext when user need that time pick from gallery

Comment: If this is the case then you need to extend the EditText and override the onDraw method and write you custom logic to render the EditText on the screen. It's not easy task to do and at the same its possible to do.

Comment: have any example code for this

Comment: Still i have completed take the images from the gallery but the image is not appear on the EditText field.

Comment: are you sure below code is not working.Can you debug and confirm.

Comment: sure its not work for me yar, would u sent me full code for import the image into the edit text

Comment: can we chat on stackoverflow?

Comment: ya sure i already in chat page only can you come?

Comment: can u send me the link for chat page.

Comment: You need atleast 20 point reputation for chat. I tested the code it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
            public Drawable getDrawable(String filePath) {
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(filePath);
                d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                return d;
            }
        };

        cs = Html.fromHtml(
                "<img src='"
                        + filePath
                        + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
        edttxtemoji.setText(cs);
```

Can you please try above code.
filePath is the path of file user has selected.

Comment: in your onActivity Result method.

Comment: is your problem solved? please accept the answer if your problem is resolved.

Comment: still i am having error, I have debug in your code i got null pointer exception.

Comment: EditText.setText(cs);

Comment: you are not initializing EditText i.e you are missing line EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.urEditTextId);

Comment: hello i have using my friend account to chat with you by (pans)

Comment: please join Android_Emoticon chatroom

Comment: Ashwin still i got a error on that line, text.setText(text.getText()+cs);    also how can i decrease the image height and width, please join in manoj chat room by pans.

Comment: I got an error in this line text.setText(text.getText()+cs);